# Importing text file and doubling array

Tags: java, arrays, import

I'm trying to write a method that imports a text file of a very large quantity of words, and then find words of a certain length and print them out. 
I'm not looking for code, but rather a clarification if I'm correctly understanding what I'm trying to accomplish.

So, I'm going to import the text using throw exception, and take the number of letters of a specific word:

```
public static void name(int size) throws Exception{
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("2of12inf.txt"));
```

And then create a new array list:

```
int[] list = new int[MAX_SIZE]; //MAX_SIZE is initially a small number, say 100
int listSize = 0;
```

Where if the size of the list of words exceeds my MAX_SIZE array, then I'm going to copy the existing array and double it, in order to have the numbers of words fit in the list.

```
if (listSize == list.length)
{
  int[] temp = new int [2*list.length];
  for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    temp[i] = list[i];}
  list = temp;
}
list[listSize] = size;
listSize++;

inputFile.close();}
```

This is my raw understanding of how I'm suppose to write the method, is this the correct thinking of just being able to read in words and give a list of them?

EDIT: Sorry, I didn't mention that I'm not to use ArrayLists.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use `ArrayList`? Also, why store words that aren't the word size you need?

Comment: Why not just use the dynamically allocated ArrayList that is already defined? E.g. `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: @AlexanderKohler Apologies, I just added in my question that I'm not to use ArrayLists. Unfortunately, I have to do it another way, and I'm wondering if this is the correct thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know which length you are interested in when before you run the program is suffices to just save those words while you iterate through the words.

Like this I mean:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class WordLengthPrinter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 2)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Specify filename as first parameter. Word length is second.");

        final String fileName = args[0]; // file name is first input argument
        final int wordLength = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); // the desired wordlength is second argument

        // lets store the words of correct size in a sorted set
        SortedSet<String> wordsOfDesiredLength = new TreeSet<String>();

        // read file line by line while checking word lengths and only store words of correct length
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName)))) {
            String line = null;
            while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.length() == wordLength) wordsOfDesiredLength.add(line);
            }
        }

        // print resulting words
        for (String word : wordsOfDesiredLength) {
            System.out.println(word);
        }
    }
}
```